# I am trying to make login module in android studio but i got the error as following..(Column name doesn't exist)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
 public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userdetail1";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "sample";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
        public static final String NAME = "username";
        public static final String PASSWORD = "u_password";
        public static final String table_create = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + NAME + "TEXT," + PASSWORD + "TEXT" + ")";


    SQLiteDatabase database;

    public Database(Context context, Object o, Object o1, int i) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(table_create);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int i, int i1) {
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(database);

    }
    public static  int flag=0;
    public void add(GetterandSetter gs)
    {
        database=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(NAME,gs.getUsername());
        values.put(PASSWORD,gs.getPassword());
        database.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        flag=1;


        database.close();
    }

}
```

I got the error stating that  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table sample has no column named username (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO sample(username,u_password) VALUES (?,?)

Comment: i already tried up cleaing appdata, reinstalling app , change the database name

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell you everything?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
NAME + "TEXT,"
```

To

```
NAME + " TEXT, "
```

You miss the space, otherwise your actually column name is **usernametext** without type.